# $\mathrm{PSL}_3(4)$ inside the Monster group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

Which quasisimple groups with central quotient $G\cong\mathrm{PSL}_3(4)$ are isomorphic to subgroups of the Monster sporadic group? So far I know that $G$ itself is not and that $2\cdot G$, $2^2\cdot G$, and $6\cdot G$ are, which leaves $3\cdot G$, both $4\cdot G$s, $(2\times4)\cdot G$, both $12\cdot G$s, $(2\times6)\cdot G$, $4^2\cdot G$, $(4\times6)\cdot G$, and $(4\times12)\cdot G$.

Answer (score 5):

The group $3.G$ centralizes an element of order three. If $3.G$ is a subgroup of the Monster then it is contained in a 3A centralizer (structure $3.Fi_{24}'$), a 3B centralizer (structure $3^{1+12}_+.2Suz$) or a 3C centralizer (structure $3 \times Th$).
Clearly the case 3C cannot occur, and 3B is excluded by the fact that no class fusion between $3.G$ and the 3B normalizer $3^{1+12}_+.2Suz.2$ is possible --GAP's `PossibleClassFusions` can be used to show this, using the known character tables of the two groups.
If $3.G$ is contained in the 3A centralizer then this embedding induces one of $G$ into some maximal subgroup of $Fi_{24}'$.  Using the known character tables of these maximal subgroups in GAP's character table library, one shows that only $Fi_{23}$ admits a class fusion, but this subgroup lifts to $3 \times Fi_{23}$ in $3.Fi_{24}'$ and thus cannot lead to a subgroup of type $3.G$.

The other candidates $m.G$ contain at least one central involution. If $m.G$ is a subgroup of the Monster then it is contained in a 2A centralizer (structure $2.B$) or a 2B centralizer (structure $2^{1+24}_+.Co_1$).
Again we use GAP's `PossibleClassFusions` to list all candidates for the class fusion, but here we prescribe the central involution of the 2A or 2B centralizer as an image of one central involution in $m.G$.
It turns out that exactly one group $m.G$ cannot be excluded this way.
Namely, these character-theoretical criteria leave the possibility that $4_1.G$ may occur as a subgroup of $2^{1+24}_+.Co_1$.